# CruiseControl JUnit test results show all zeroes

Tags: java, junit, cruisecontrol

I've got JUnit hooked up with CruiseControl and unit tests are being executed & logs imported, but CruiseControl shows the following output:

```
nz.co.picksend.core.tests.nz.co.picksend.core.dal.FilterTests 
Tests: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Duration: 0.0
nz.co.picksend.core.tests.nz.co.picksend.core.dal.ModelObjectRegistryTests 
Tests: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Duration: 0.0
nz.co.picksend.core.tests.nz.co.picksend.core.dal.ModelObjectSetTests 
Tests: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Duration: 0.0
nz.co.picksend.core.tests.nz.co.picksend.core.humanresources.AllHumanResourcesTests 
Tests: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Duration: 0.0
```

(Note all zeroes)

However, the log files that are being merged look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<testsuite errors="1" failures="0" hostname="maudslay"
    name="nz.co.picksend.core.tests.nz.co.picksend.core.rules.MockEvalRule" tests="1"
    time="0.0" timestamp="2009-11-04T23:05:19">
<properties>
    ...
</properties>
<error message="nz.co.picksend.core.tests.nz.co.picksend.core.rules.MockEvalRule"
    type="java.lang.ClassNotFoundException">
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
    nz.co.picksend.core.tests.nz.co.picksend.core.rules.MockEvalRule
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
</error>
<system-out><![CDATA[]]></system-out>
<system-err><![CDATA[]]></system-err>
</testsuite>
```

Here's the snippet from ant's build.xml:

```
<target name="test">
    <junit errorProperty="test.failed" failureProperty="test.failed">
    <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
        <formatter type="xml" />
        <batchtest todir="${buildresults.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}">
                <include name="nz.co*/**/tests/**/*.java" />
                <include name="nz.co*/**/test/**/*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
<fail message="Tests failed: check test reports." if="test.failed" />
</target>
```

and finally, here's the project's snippet from cruisecontrol's config.xml:

```
<project requiremodification="false" name="Pick and Send">
    <modificationset QuietPeriod="30">
        ....
    </modificationset>
    <schedule Interval="300" ShowProgress="true">
        <ant AntWorkingDir="E:\Build\PickSend2" 
        BuildFile="E:\Build\PickSend2\build.xml" 
        Time="0400" Target="bat" anthome="apache-ant-1.7.0" />
    </schedule>
    <log>
        <merge Dir="E:\Build\PickSend2\buildresults" />
    </log>
    <bootstrappers>
        ....
    </bootstrappers>
</project>
```

Has anyone had this situation before?

Comment: Your output  contains packages like: "nz.co.picksend.core.tests.nz.co.picksend.core.rules". I notice that "nz.co.picksend.core" appears twice in the package name. I cannot tell if this is (un)intentional? Possibly the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - this is actually intentional. nz.co.picksend.core is both the project and package base name, so the source tree looks like /nz.co.picksend.core/tests/nz/co/picksend/core/...

Comment: That could be the part of the problem too! Your source tree is "/nz.co.picksend.core/tests/nz/co/picksend/core/.."; Junit is looking for "nz.co.picksend.core.tests.nz.co.picksend.core.rules.MockEvalRule"; which it expects to find in "nz/co/picksend/core/tests/nz/co/picksend/core/rules/MockEvalRule.class" (just replace "."s with "/"s). I would consider refactoring the package name to exclude "."s, and see how that goes.

Comment: @bguiz, you should post as an answer.  I think you are correct.

Comment: Just to back up the previous statements. I doubt you can use dots (full stops) in your package name. JLS (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.8) defines the characters that can be used as part of Java identifiers. And a dot is not one of them. You can check it by running `Character.isJavaIdentifierPart('.')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because of the unit test throwing an error, not in the test itself, but in the test's setup. This for some reason isn't captured by cruisecontrol.